# how to update in bulk the requirements.txt file in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have around 200 functions developed in Python deployed in GCP as a Cloud Functions.
I need to update one library in the for all this functions.
How can I update requirements.txt in all this functions massively in one single shot, without go one by one?
It's possible?

Comment: How is your source directory structured? Are you upgrading to a specific version or just the latest?

Comment: I need to update to a specific version. 
I have around 200 functions and each of this functions basically has 2 files. The code (a .py file) and the requirements.txt.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have source code of 200 cloud functions downloaded, you can write a bash/python script to update requirements.txt of each of those.